# Visual Studio C++: The object or library file was created with an older compiler than other objects (BWAPI)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to use BWAPI for a starcraft bot, but whenever I compile, it returns an error stating, that BWAPI.lib is compiled with a previous version of visual studio. The only problem is, that I can't (or don't know how to) recompile it, because I can't find the source online. How could I solve this?  Also I'm using VS2015 Community

Comment: Also, if I turn off Whole Program Optimization, then I get a bunch of "mismatch detected" and some "unresolved external symbol" errors, which I'm guessing is just the side effect of the first error

Comment: Generally, all components of a C++ program (object files, libraries and whatnot) need to be compiled with the *exact same* compiler. So, better learn how to recompile that library *now* - you'll need the general knowledge many times again in the future.

Comment: I know how to recompile things, the only problem is the missing project I could compile

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the [source code](https://github.com/bwapi/bwapi/archive/v4.1.2.zip) for version 4.1.2, loaded the solution file into VS2015, done a few modifications and compiled successfully. 
You're looking for the source code of an older version?